# On Area 51, once a proposed question enters the "on-topic", "off-topic" or "bad example" category, can it be locked?

Tags: feature-request, area-51, voting

I don't have raw numbers, but a quick glance around shows me that people are continuning to vote on questions that have already been deemed as either on-topic, off-topic, or a bad example by the community. These people might not realize this, either. So instead of allowing people to vote on questions that are already categorized, can it be locked so that they have to vote on another question? I think this might help the sites stuck in the definition phase, too. As new people come, they'll only vote on questions that need to be voted on.

Comment: I'm assuming there's a reason behind the Good Question and Great Question badges. If this were implemented, they would be impossible to get.

Comment: Honestly, they should be replaced with "on-topic question" and "off-topic question" badges that you get every time one of your questions is nominated as on or off topic (as both are seen as "good things" - the "bad thing" being "non a good example").

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if a question gained the 20 votes needed to be classified as "on topic" but then someone decided it wasn't a good example and wanted to vote it as either "off topic" or (more likely) "not a good example"?

Wouldn't they be prevented from doing so by locking?

Or are you proposing that only "on topic" votes (for example) be blocked? In this case you'd have to continually check that the question still met the criteria and unblock votes if necessary.

It seems a lot of work for very little gain.

Comment: I would say lock the question totally. If the majority of 20 people have decided that it's on topic, then it's on topic. Unless you can point me to instances where a question has gone between being on-topic and off-topic (or bad example), it appears that most questions just sit there and get more and more votes in whatever direction they were going in.